# JMeter inconsistent CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jmeter, amazon-rds

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 976,464 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 974,674 milliseconds ago.
```

This error occurs in JMeter when I ran the following test plan that would send 15 MB files to AWS RDS.

```
LoadTestPlan
  JDBC Connection Configuration: 
     Max Wait ms: 0 (indefinite wait)
     Max connections: 0 (no limit)
  ThreadGroup
      No. of threads: 200
      Ramp up seconds: 100
      Loop Count: Indefinite
      Scheduled to run for 3 hours
    JDBC Request
       LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE statement
```

RDS Configuration

```
Engine 5.7.33
Max connections: 200
Innodb lock wait timeout: 6000
Max allowed packet: 64 MB
```

There were many solutions for this Communication Links Failure but for me, some requests are successful and for some I get this error. Thus I am starting to think it is the network problem but I am using high speed Ethernet of 74 Mbps speed. Even if it is the network problem there must be some parameter that when adjusted should allow connections from even poor network to be successful.

JMter version: 5.4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your statement:

> Max connections: 0 (no limit)

I don't think it's true, as per [BasicDataSource Configuration Parameters](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) I would say it's rather `8` (see `maxTotal` parameter)

[image]

So it looks like you're using 200 concurrent threads and having 8 connections in pool, try increasing these max connections to be equal to the number of JMeter threads. Or if you're not testing the database directly you should rather mimic your application [JDBC configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity).

I know that JMeter tries to set maximum pool size equal to initial pool size as it evidenced by [this line](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/protocol/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jdbc/config/DataSourceElement.java#L245), however [the source code of BasicDataSource suggests setting a negative number for "no limit"](https://github.com/apache/commons-dbcp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/dbcp2/BasicDataSource.java#L2233)

More information: [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter)

Comment: The Max Number of Connections field was empty. I changed it to 0 so that I will not have any limits. I read "Maximum number of connections allowed in the pool. In most cases, set this to zero (0). This means that each thread will get its own pool with a single connection in it, i.e. the connections are not shared between threads." from http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration